# vbscript syntax in asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a vbscript that I want to run in the `<head>` of an asp. I am having trouble getting the script to run so I'm thinking I need some help making sure the asp knows that it's vvbscript or something. The last script is the one I am having trouble running.

here is what I have:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%

    ***vbscript***

%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MD_intstyle.css" type="text/css">
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">

     ***javascript***

</script>

<script language="vbscript">
     ***vbscript I am trying to run***
</script>

</HEAD>
```

Comment: I don't really have the option of changing it... I would if I could believe me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 <script language="vbscript">
 ***vbscript I am trying to run***
 </script>
```

To:

```
<%
***vbscript I am trying to run***
%>
```

AS(erver)P runs on the server and therefore you cant tell the client to run the code as vbscript with HTML-tags. Start your ASP code with the start tag <% and the close tag %>. Just as you do on the top in your example.

Answer (score 1):

use runat="server" in script tag.

```
 <script language="vbscript" runat="server">
      ***vbscript I am trying to run***
 </script>
```