# Unable to use Response.Write in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am supporting an old Classic ASP application and I've read that the code we write within `<%  %>` is VBScript and `<% Response.Write "VBScript" %>` is working fine , but when I write in the following format, Response.Write is not working

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Response.Write "VBScript"
</SCRIPT>
```

also Response.Write is not getting executed in an button click event

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" >

    function B3_OnClick()

     FORM1.T3.style.backgroundColor = "white"
     FORM1.T4.style.backgroundColor = "white"
     FORM1.T3.readOnly ="false"
     FORM1.T4.readOnly ="false"
     FORM1.style.backgroundColor = "white"
     Response.Write("Hello World")

    End function 

   </SCRIPT>
```

Can Anyone explain me why? Is there any substitute for Response.Write in that case..? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vbscript syntax in asp classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611493/vbscript-syntax-in-asp-classic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are missing the `runat="Server"` attribute in the `<script>` tag.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" runat="Server">
Response.Write "VBScript"
</SCRIPT>
```

Remember VBScript accessed through Classic ASP happens **before** the response is sent to the client. For an action such as clicking a button on the client to affect the server-side code it has to make a round-trip to the server. If you want to have server-side code affect client-side code you can inject code before returning a server response to the client.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" >

 function B3_OnClick()

  FORM1.T3.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  FORM1.T4.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  FORM1.T3.readOnly ="false"
  FORM1.T4.readOnly ="false"
  FORM1.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  MsgBox "<% Response.Write("Hello World") %>"

 End function 

</SCRIPT>
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Answer to Access client variable within server-tags in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34923474/692942)
- [Answer to what's the difference between <% %> and  in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449277/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart....Thanks bro for your reply. I've used `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"  runat = "server">`and I wrote the button click event. But still after clicking button `Response.Write` isn't working..Can u please say where I m going wrong.

Comment: I've removed MsgBox and using only `Response.Write("Hello World")` in Button click event by adding  `runat = "server">`

Comment: @METALHEAD The problem is you are trying to use "server-side" code the same as "client-side" code. In terms of the lifecycle of a Classic ASP page it goes `-> Request -> Server processes response -> Response Sent` but you want to interact with it before `Request` is sent which cannot be done. What you can do is effect the `Response`, so the client-side code here can have `<% Response.Write("Hello World") %>` injected into it which in effect gives you `MsgBox "Hello World"` when the client script runs once the response is returned and a button is clicked.

Comment: @METALHEAD If you are still struggling to understand go view the "Page Source" in the Internet Browser to see what `<% Response.Write("Hello world") %>` has become, without the `MsgBox "..."` you'll likely get a VBScript syntax error. [This diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TDNeH.gif) explains it perfectly.